# bind-sdb does not query for wildcard entry

Tags: ldap, bind, openldap

I have successfully set up Bild with LDAP on a Fedora VM.
The Problem is, bind-sdb simply does not query wildcard entries.

When I do:
nslookup doesnotexist.example.com. 127.0.0.1

The LDAP server gets the reuqest and answers with an error as I expect it to do. After that, bind-sdb queries for the @ entry several times.

What I would expect it to do is query some kind of wildcard entry. One of the other projects (bind-dlz) describe this as the ~ entry because LDAP is using * in queries for itself (or as I think, bind-sdb queries aren't that good).

But in the log there is no such query.